# How to salvage stuff from git repo damaged by rm -r disaster followed by partially successful undelete?

Tags: git

I had a rm -r disaster over a source tree with a git repository, and the subsequent partially successful undelete brought back a zombie repo that doesn't function at all. Very unfortunately this repo contained several branches that were only present there. Work was lost.

Are there any tools in existence that can try to salvage code from the remains of a massacred repository?

Comment: Was the repository pushed anywhere else? Does anyone have a clone?

Comment: You recover from backup.

Comment: @bmargulies Sure, next time this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're interested in files inside `.git` directory, if `.git/refs/heads` survived - it contains files with hashes of commits at your branches

Also try comparing a healthy repo's `.git/objects` from upstream and yours, you're interested in objects that are not in upstream, of course
and may be [git object browser](https://github.com/koseki/git-object-browser) would open them

Comment: Thanks! Exactly the kind of tool I asked about, even though I had no luck with it in this particular case.